# How to control a Service from both remote and local?

Tags: android, service, ipc, aidl

I have situation: My App has a local Service(used to pool slave devices), the app is able to start or stop the pool. However, other authorized apps will have the ability to start or stop the pool, and when they do so, they will alse passes values to the service(such as slave address). How can I control the service from both remote and local, will they have conflicts?

Comment: Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two functions to perform start and stop operations in your app, like:

`public startPool(String address){}
public stopPool(String address) {}`

then there are high chances of conflict if they will be called from multiple threads. Conflict can be handled by two approach :

1. [Synchronization](http://www.javatpoint.com/synchronization-in-java)
2. Using [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) to queue your request, so that it all happens in serial fashion.